Thermodynamics of T-symmetry violation
Physics is mostly time reversible. But certain nuclear interactions violate this T symmetry.
With T-symmetry a system at maximum entropy has no "arrow of time". Thus a video of the system looks the same when played forward or played in reverse. Which in turn means a dead system with no macroscopic change.
But without T symmetry there is always an inherent "distinction" between future and past. This would seem to force some sort of macroscopic evolution even when starting from a maximum entropy state.
An extreme version of T-symmetry violation is Conway's game of Life, within which entropy can easily be destroyed.
My logic is wrong of course. T-symmetry violations won't save us from hear-death. What is the flaw in my logic?

The link is not nuclear interactions but a particle interaction in the realm of Lorentz invariance and quantum mechanics. The CPT https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPT_symmetry is basic in particle physics, axiomatic. Because of the CPT symmetry where there exists CP violation the symmetry predicts T violation, that is what the link is checking.

I don't get your logic. If you start with a maximum entropy system (closed) how can a process happen (without the other process happening in reverse) that would decrease the entropy? I mean, weak interaction/decay is indeed not T symmetric, but even those happen in accordance to increasing entropy. One example is the Sakharov conditions, which also include thermodynamic considerations, despite naively CP (or T) violation already being there
